# AttributeError: 'DType' object has no attribute 'char'

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras

I have a tensor whose dtype is printed as:

```
<dtype: 'float32'>
```

However, when I pass this tensor to a built-in function,it checks for the following condition:

```
x.dtype.char in numpy.typecodes["AllFloat"]
```

and
 I get the error:

```
AttributeError: 'DType' object has no attribute 'char'
```

How do I make this tensor produce a dtype.char value?

Comment: Could you provide reproducible code?

Comment: @rvinas Please check the link: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50559152/custom-layer-in-keras-for-idct